# Use JSON result in query using Ruby, Sinatra and PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby, json, postgresql, sinatra

I am using Ruby and the Plivo api to create a subaccount.

The code is:

```
AUTH_ID = "my_id"
AUTH_TOKEN = "my_token"

p = RestAPI.new(AUTH_ID, AUTH_TOKEN)
params = {'name' => 'thegreatone'}
response = p.create_subaccount(params)
```

// up to here is fine and (without my attempts below to access the json response) it works and the account is created.

The JSON response is :

```
[{"auth_token"=>"ZjgxMGQwMTY2NGY3Nzk3ZmM3ZGE3ZmIxMGQyZWYy",
  "message"=>"created",
  "api_id"=>"2c1eff4a-b955-11e2-8361-123141011ae6",
  "auth_id"=>"SAMZBJOGZKZDIXMMEXNJ"}]
```

I would like to "extract" the "auth_token" and "auht_id" so that I can insert them into my database.

So I have tried (among other things):

```
obj = JSON.parse(response)
:user_key = obj['auth_token']
```

the message in my terminal is:

syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting $end

```
:user_key = obj['auth_token']
```

How can I extract these variables and then pass them to my insert query?

I am using postgres with SEQUEL, ruby and sinatra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to assign a value to a symbol and the response returns an array:

```
obj = JSON.parse(response)
:user_key = obj['auth_token']
```

should be

```
obj = JSON.parse(response).first
user_key = obj['auth_token']
```

symbols are not variables, they are constants.

Comment: thank you, unfortunately that does not work. The response (in my terminal) is  "can't convert Array into String (TypeError)". When I remove the code block 

obj = JSON.parse(response)
user_key = obj['auth_token']

and do pp response I get:

[201,
 {"auth_token"=>"NTY2NTc4YzJlMTcyNmE5MWQ5OTU2MjNkYWU0NDg0",
  "message"=>"created",
  "api_id"=>"4c5ad5a8-b960-11e2-ba1a-22000abc182f",
  "auth_id"=>"SAMJQWODAXNJA2OTGZM2"}]

Comment: @user1903663 See Chris Farmiloe's edit above - your returned structure was an array of hashes, not a singular hash, hence your warning above.

Comment: thank you, I have tried obj = JSON.parse(response).first and obj = JSON.parse(response).last the result is the same:

onvert Array into String (TypeError)

Answer (score 0):

The response is an array containing the code response and then the data, so your code should be

```
obj = JSON.parse(response).last
user_key = obj['auth_token']
```

Edit: Turns out the gem already do the parse for you  [plivo.rb](https://github.com/plivo/plivo-ruby/blob/master/lib/plivo.rb). So the code would be:

```
obj = response.last
user_key = obj['auth_token']
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried obj = JSON.parse(response).last and the error was: 

can't convert Array into String (TypeError)

Comment: Ok I know what the problem is, the gem (https://github.com/plivo/plivo-ruby/blob/master/lib/plivo.rb) already do the parsing for you so you only have to take the object. I modifies my response

Comment: brilliant, thank you very much. Last question, if I may ...  how can I "echo" is in PHP speak just to be sure what each element is? Is there a way of formatting json response into HTML?

Comment: The equivalento of echo in ruby is puts or pp (pretty puts) but this will only work in the console. I see you tagged it as Sinatra, the best way to 'convert' it into HTML is to use the Sinatra template system: http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Views%20/%20Templates. The templates will inherit your class variables, so you could do something like '@obj = response.last', and @obj will be also available in your templates

Comment: great that sounds very cool. Much obliged, just starting out on ruby!